# What is the term for the physical and behavioral changes that occur in an adult species due to the change in their hierarchy?

Tags: physiology, ethology, endocrinology, sociality, sociobiology

For example, when a chicken becomes a rooster its crest becomes larger and their feathers become more colorful. Dominant male lions get larger and darker manes.

Also, can these changes also occur inversely? If so, what is the term for it?